# How to know the size of a text when using Canvas.drawText()

Tags: android, canvas, drawtext

I'm using the Canvas.drawText() to write text on a custom view. 
I want to add a background 9-patch drawable behind the text, so I need to know the boundaries of the text drawn. 
The text is given by the user, so it's not a fixed size.

For now I'm using a monospace font and I managed to build a size which looks not so bad, but in the hand i'd rather use another font.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `public void getTextBounds(String text, int start, int end, Rect bounds)` method of Paint to get a rectangle that encloses all your text. Take a look at [getTextBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextAlign()).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think `getTextBounds(String text, int start, int end, Rect bounds)` can do it for you.

This method belongs to Paint class:

[Refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630086/how-to-get-string-width-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

You also may use measureText

```
mTextTimeColorPaint.measureText(timeText)
```

Like in this post [Center Text on Watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929671/center-text-on-watch)