# Center Text on Watch

Tags: android, android-service, wear-os

I've been trying multiple ways to center 3 lines of text on a watch and can't seem to figure it out.  The new watch face services require you to paint to a canvas.  I initialize the text offset by grabbing the length of text of each line and dividing by 2.

```
mXDateOffset = mTextDateColorPaint.measureText("May 21, 2015") /2;
mXTimeOffset = mTextTimeColorPaint.measureText("12:00:00")/2;
mXBatteryOffset = mTextBatteryColorPaint.measureText("99%") /2 ;
```

Then when I set the text and paint elements to the canvas I find the center of the rectangle(screen) minus the screen to find the start position of the text.

```
canvas.drawText( timeText, bounds.centerX() - mXTimeOffset, 40.0f, mTextTimeColorPaint );
canvas.drawText( date, bounds.centerX() - mXDateOffset, 90.0f, mTextDateColorPaint);
canvas.drawText( mBatteryLevel, bounds.centerX() - mXBatteryOffset, 130.0f, mTextBatteryColorPaint );
```

What I get is this...

[image]

Not sure what else to do.

Comment: that seems very well centered to me, just not for the actual text you are drawing. mind you, `4:39:41` does not have the same length as `12:00:00`. I don't really understand why you would use a different text for measuring and for drawing.

Comment: Initial default conditions...

Comment: then you just have to change the offset value according to whatever you want to draw...

Comment: So I have to manually measure the text length each time and the center it?  Isn't there an easier way?  I miss the Textfield layouts we used to have for watchfaces

Comment: yes. but it is quite easy. Just do `canvas.drawText( timeText, bounds.centerX() - mTextTimeColorPaint.measureText(timeText)/2, 40.0f, mTextTimeColorPaint );`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is alot that went into this answer here is what I came up with having to access the onDraw methods:

in onCreate() set the offsets

```
mYTimeOffset = getResources().getDimension( R.dimen.y_offset );
mYDateOffset = getResources().getDimension( R.dimen.y_date_offset );
mYBatteryOffset = getResources().getDimension( R.dimen.y_battery_offset );
```

then call the drawtime and set the canvas parameters

```
    private void drawTimeText(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
        String timeText = getHourString() + ":" + String.format( "%02d", mDisplayTime.minute );
        if( isInAmbientMode() || mIsInMuteMode ) {
            timeText += ( mDisplayTime.hour < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";
        } else {
            timeText += String.format( ":%02d", mDisplayTime.second);
        }

        String date = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_DISPLAYED).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        canvas.drawText( timeText, bounds.centerX() - (mTextTimeColorPaint.measureText(timeText))/2, mYTimeOffset, mTextTimeColorPaint );
        canvas.drawText( date, bounds.centerX() - (mTextDateColorPaint.measureText(date))/2, mYDateOffset, mTextDateColorPaint);
        if (mBatteryLevel != null)
        canvas.drawText( mBatteryLevel, bounds.centerX() - (mTextBatteryColorPaint.measureText(mBatteryLevel))/2, mYBatteryOffset, mTextBatteryColorPaint );
    }
```