# Android - get text advance?

Tags: android

Regarding setting the font size for an Android app, is there a way I can test the size of any text, like
Font.getAdvance(String)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Paint.measureText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29).

You can refer this question also: [How to get string width on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630086/how-to-get-string-width-on-android)