# How to calculate the width of the string

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get string width on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630086/how-to-get-string-width-on-android)

I use the following code to calculate the width of the string, but the result of the width is considerably different from the width which displayed in TextView. How can I make this correctly? Thanks in advice.

```
Paint paint= new Paint(); 
        paint.setTextSize(size);


        int iRet = 0;  
        if (str != null && str.length() > 0) {  
                int len = str.length();  
                float[] widths = new float[len];  
                paint.getTextWidths(str, widths);  
                for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {  
                    iRet += (int) Math.ceil(widths[j]);  
                }  
        }  
        return iRet;
```

Comment: [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3630086/1050058). You guys should flag duplicated to encourage new guys search before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code, I hope it will help you..

```
Paint paint= new Paint(); 
paint.setTextSize(size);
int txtWidth = (int)(paint.measureText("Hello how are you?"));
```