# Usability of BoringLayout

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm writing a custom layout that will manage text. 
Before I started implementing the `ViewGroup#onMeasure()` method I started to dig the EditText source code, specifically at the `EditText#onMeasure()` method. So I came across the  [`BoringLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/BoringLayout.html). I read the docs but I didn't find much explanation on it and how to use it in an actual custom implementation. Then my question is how can I use it the right way and when it is really needed.

Comment: Hi, could you be a little more specific? BoringLayout is not really meant to manage text. What do you mean when you say "manage text?" A little more detail about what your app should do will help greatly, code samples are even better.

Comment: @Otra I meant my layout will be managing text according to text width of some component. `BoringLayout` would help me achieve that by giving me the metrics of the text. I want to know how it can be applied correctly.

Comment: You may no need an entire layout for that. See if this answer helps any: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630086/how-to-get-string-width-on-android

Comment: I'm trying to investigate BoringLayout as since I've read on the Android documentation the next:

You should not need to use this class directly unless you are implementing your own widget or custom display object, in which case you are encouraged to use a Layout instead of calling Canvas.drawText() directly.

I've always used Canvas.drawText(), I'm doing this wrong?

Comment: wrong is relative, nothing prevents you from drawing yourself on the canvas but BoringLayout is here to help you in that task.  All the framework widgets I know of use it instead of drawing directly on the canvas. The documentation of this class is very lacking though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`BoringLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/BoringLayout.html) is used to draw text on a view. It is called "boring" because it only handles a single line of left-to-right text without any interesting characters such as emoji. This simplification allows the class to override `onDraw` with more efficient logic than the default does. [Here is the source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/BoringLayout.java) if you want to see for yourself.

Like [`StaticLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html) and [`DynamicLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/DynamicLayout.html), the `BoringLayout` is also a subclass of the abstract [`Layout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html) class. As the documentation says, you probably wouldn't use these classes directly unless you are making your own text handling widget. How do you know if you should be using one of these classes? If you are thinking about using [`Canvas.drawText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) in your custom view, then you should probably think about using a `Layout`. They also eventually call `Canvas.drawText`, but they do a lot of other processing beforehand.

If you are making your own text widget, then you would only use the `BoringLayout` for single line, simple, left-to-right text. For multi-line and more complex text use a `StaticLayout`. And if you need to dynamically change the text after creation, then use a `DynamicLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can draw text on the canvas with `canvas.drawText("text");
However, text is a very general term and can get extremely complicated : is it LeftToRight or RightToLeft ? is it Ellipsized ? is it single or multiLine ? ...

android.text.Layout is here to handle all this.

the typical way to use it is :

```
        BoringLayout.Metrics boring = BoringLayout.isBoring(mText, mPaint);
    if (boring != null) {
        // this is boring !
        if (mSavedLayout != null) {
            mLayout = mSavedLayout.replaceOrMake(mText,
                    mPaint,
                    availableWidth,
                    Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
                    SPACING_MULT,
                    SPACING_ADD,
                    boring,
                    true,
                    TextUtils.TruncateAt.END,
                    availableWidth);
        } else {
            mLayout = BoringLayout.make(mText,
                    mPaint,
                    availableWidth,
                    Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
                    SPACING_MULT,
                    SPACING_ADD,
                    boring,
                    true,
                    TextUtils.TruncateAt.END,
                    availableWidth);
        }
        mSavedLayout = (BoringLayout) mLayout;
    } else {
        mLayout = new StaticLayout(mText,
                0,
                mText.length(),
                mPaint,
                availableWidth,
                Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
                SPACING_MULT,
                SPACING_ADD,
                true,
                TextUtils.TruncateAt.END,
                availableWidth);
    }
```

Comment: How to declare mLayout?

Comment: as an `android.text.Layout`, parent class for both

Comment: when i declare as the parent, the paramater helper list `ctrl-p` shows all with strike through.  Not sure if that is telling me anything.  Seems to work otherwise.