# I want to set popup width at run time according to title size in android

Tags: android, android-layout, popup, popupwindow

i tried many things but didn't get any solution, i m setting text at runtime and i need the width of popup according to text size
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context)
                    .findViewById(R.id.popup);

```
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context

        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);
        title_tv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.popup_txt);

        title_tv.setText(title_P);


         PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
final float SCALE = layout.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
 popup.setWidth(measuredWidth);
         popup.setHeight(60);


        popup.setContentView(layout);
        //popup.setWindowLayoutMode();

        popup.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630086/how-to-get-string-width-on-android

Comment: thanks, i tried it but same problem, i m getting text width by this formula & i m passing it to popup width as well but size is still not according to text..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use:

```
popup.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

plus, if applicable:

```
popup.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

However, make sure you're not using fill/match_parent in the contents of popup_layout, because that wouldn't make sense (i.e. popup set to wrap its content, and the content says make me as big as my parent). Post your popup_layout XML for a more exact answer.

Comment: @nmw i have tried this but popup window going outside of screen instead of upside when space is not available. i have different size of content so i can't give static width and height.. is there any solution?

Comment: @Sanket you got any solution?