# How to get actual bounding box(width) of font, not just text advance

Tags: iphone, nsstring, sizewithfont

I need the size (a bounding box) wrapping a string with a specific font. The font has letters which extend into neighbouring letters.

```
NSString *string = @"Letter Typed";
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BlackChancery" size:10.0f];
CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:myFont];
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:) the above will give me the bounding box of the string in the font, the problem is it doesn't for my specific font. It seems to give me the advance, ie. the number of pixels the cursor should be advanced when drawing the string. For my specific font [Black Chancery](http://www.dafont.com/black-chancery.font) many capital letters like L and K extend into the next letters.

Is there a way on iOS to get the actual bounding box or number of drawn pixels when drawing for instance 'R' with this font?

(For android there is a way to get the different measurements, as mentioned in my own answer to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630086/how-to-get-string-width-on-android/18205071#18205071))