# How to get a pixel width of a string in android?

Tags: android

A string as "123456" showed in the screen. I want to get the width of that string .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3630331/983741 CHeck this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I dont tried, but maybe something like that:

```
mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setTextSize(64);
//...
float width = mPaint.measureText(text, 0, text.length());
```