# Can I set text in a TextView to fill lower lines first when on more than one line

Tags: android, textview

I'm looking to place text in a `TextView` with a **fixed width**, and which can be spread over **two lines**, but what I want is to do is to place as much of the text towards the **bottom** as possible. For example, this is current what happens:

```
 The quick brown fox jumps over 
 the lazy dog
```

But what I want to happen is:

```
 The quick brown
 fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Does anyone have any ideas how, if possible, this might be achieved using just one `TextView`?

Comment: I don't think there's any automatic solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Aleks that there probably isn't a built-in solution for this. You'll probably need to do some clever manipulations. One possible solution might be to create your own `TextView` that takes the `String` and calculates where to split the `String` and draw it accordingly.

You can use the following code (reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3630331/394933)) to get the width of a `String` if it were to be rendered in a `TextView`:

```
Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
float width = textPaint.measureText(string);
```

You could then use information about the width of your `TextView` to calculate where to "chop" the `String` and draw it. It's a solution that'll need perfecting, but that's what I would try.