# Get string length in pixels

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that looks as follows:

```
|User Name      |      |
|email@mail.com | info |
```

And I need to set user's first name and second name if it fits into TextView and only first name if first name and second name is too long for current screen.

For example for "Tom Smith":

```
|Tom Smith      |      |
|email@mail.com | info |
```

and for "Tom VeryVeryVeryLongSurname":

```
|Tom            |      |
|email@mail.com | info |
```

How can I get a name size with specified text size and compare it with TextView width?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630086/how-to-get-string-width-on-android

Answer (score 0):

See `TextPaint#getTextBounds` method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28char[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29

And other from the `TextPaint` and `Paint` classes

Paint.html#measureText seems to be even more matching what you are looking for.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int%29

Anyway look at the `android.graphics.Paint` class.

Comment: Thank you!

How can I get width of space between left screen border and next View?