# Android textview wrap custom view

Tags: android

I have `TextView` and custom view called `StarRating`.

There is code snippet:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/flowtextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.app.views.StarRating
        android:id="@+id/star_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:text="by Legacy Reviewer, April 11, 2014 from Chicago IL"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/star_rating" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Actual Result:
[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

The problem is that `TextView` is not wrapping the `StarRating`...

How can I do that ?

Comment: use `LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2` in your `TextView`

Comment: The only idea which comes to my mind is to give  textview android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent", put before your text whitespaces which would create non-text area needed for starsview, before that you need to calculate how much space would be needded. Another option is to create custom view.

Comment: If you want to make specific text start in new line you can use \n in string values :)

Comment: just google for `LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2 wrap text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not HTML. In standard TextView text is layouted within TextView boundaries (rectangle), so this is working as expected. You cannot make it work differently as these views won't work that way and if they overlap they do not know about this anyway.

Comment: not really, you can use a TextView's magic weapon: spans, `LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2` in particular

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski You re right that it works as expected, but we can make some tricks which create our desired layout.

Comment: @MyWay please, no hacks, just use a span i mentioned above

Comment: @MyWay, no hacks, no tricks, spans are the normal way of changing `TextView`'s look

Comment: @pskink you're right

Comment: @pskink please post your answer as answer

Comment: I was referring to the way views are drawn, but you're right I should have mention spans here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:gravity="center"`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/flowtextView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is add extra spaces in the beginning of your text. it's a little tricky though.

let me know if you want more details.

Comment: Please provide details!

Comment: if rating view is clickable then most probably with this way textview will overlap rating bar making it unclickable

Comment: @VivekMishra not really, if u use frame layout and rating view will be above textview it will works right.

Comment: @MyWay OP edited his answer after my comment. Earlier he said using `Relative Layout` so according to that my point is valid

Comment: I guess both ways are good....frame layout and relative layout

Comment: I have an idea which not tested yet, but i think by using this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3630331/4310784), u can have your size per character. after that, with having width of each star or whole StartRating view, can calculate necessary spaces to put before your text.