# Is it possible to relate string length to text view width?

Tags: android, textview

I have a Text view that has a max width of (200 dp). And I have a string that varies in length.

**Example**

Lets say that the string is this:

```
   String example= "this is a test string";
```

**question:**

I want to know if is it possible to check if the length of the string is equal to the text view's maximum width?

Thank you.

Comment: Why you are give static width (200 dp) in your project.

Comment: @KaushalGosaliya I want it to be maximum 200 dp.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
```

With this:

```
textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, example.length(), bounds);
```

That information is from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3630331/3857465) that may probably help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add ***android:singleLine="true"*** in your text view to solve your problem.

```
<TextView
        android:text="this is a test stringthis is a test string
        this is a test stringthis is a test string"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: @database Can you please try this answer It may be help full.